# Can't edit *.jsp file

Tags: jsp

I wanted to understand what a *.jsp file is doing from a website. So I downloaded that file. Also, in order to edit it, I downloaded "lomboz" with eclipse to open this. But when I opened the file, it displayed junk characters! (But I'm sure it worked fine with browser, I just wanted to see the code behind it.)

Is this because the developer had encoded the *.jsp file in some way (for security reasons)? Or it just because I am doing something wrong?

This is what I got

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a plain text editor?

Comment: Please show some snippets of the "junk" you're seeing, preferably the first few lines. Surely one must be able to recognize the "junk" and explain you what's going on and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first line:

> ```
> ÿØÿà  JFIF
> ```

That's not a JSP file. That's a [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) file. Rename it to `.jpg` and open it with an image viewer. Perhaps you were just taking a screenshot of the JSP result in the webbrowser.

Note that there is **no** way to get/download JSP source code by just viewing the page in some webbrowser. JSP runs on webserver, produces some bunch of HTML upon a HTTP request, webserver sends that HTML to webbrowser and webbrowser displays that HTML. The JSP source code has to be obtained from the local disk file system in the webserver which usually takes place by FTP or SCP.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I recommend using just ["Eclipse for Java EE"](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) instead of "Lomboz" to develop with Java EE web applications (including JSP/Servlet). To get started with JSP/Servlet, I recommend to get yourself through our tag wiki pages:

- [JSP tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Servlets tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

They in turn contain several tutorial links at the bottom.

Comment: Yea, I just took a snapshot of my screen. Since I didn't own the code, I think I can't upload the code file here. Sorry.

Comment: Or do you mean it originally is a JPEG file?

Comment: I was talking about the "junk" file you're having, not about the screenshot of the "junk".

Comment: Ah, I see! Seems the originally *.jpg file from the website generate image back. So when I saved the webpage, I only saved the image. Wow, that's so silly. Thank you:)

Because the jsp file I wanted to download return random image to client. Is there anyway to check what is inside the jsp file rather than the image it return?

Comment: No. You have got to have an open connection to the webserver's disk file system. Usually FTP or SCP is been used for this. You only need to know the hostname:port and login username/password. Contact the server admin for details.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if that website is completely outside your control (i.e. it's someone else's), and you would like to achieve the same functionality using JSPs, then feel free to post a concrete question about that. We may be able to explain how to achieve the same in JSP. Beware that the question is not **too** broad, it would get closed, you've got to bring in and show moderate programming effort in order to achieve the same.

Comment: Ah, also, is the file extension with *.do another java source code that I can't just download it from website and edit it with Eclipse?

Comment: Server side web languages runs on webserver upon a HTTP request from a webbrowser, produces a bunch of HTML which the webserver sends back as HTTP response to the webbrowser. So, no, you aren't ever going to get the server side source code by a simple HTTP request. It's stored in the local disk file system of the webserver. What part exactly do you still not understand?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I got it. I just wanted to know if *.do is also server side web language. Thank you again:)

Comment: All what you can get in the client side is whatever the webbrowser has downloaded from the webserver. Rightclick page and *View Source*. You see, it's all plain HTML, CSS, JavaScript and a bunch of images. The `*.do` extension is typical for a Struts based webapp.